# Quarkus + resteasy-multipart

Tags: multipartform-data, resteasy, multipart, quarkus

Any way I could use a boolean as text/plain in a MultipartBody?

Using Quarkus 1.10.5.Final,

```
@FormParam("myMap")
@PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Map<Integer, String> myMap;
```

works now.

But I still have issues with:

```
@PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public boolean flag;
```

--
I got it to work as JSON like this:

```
@PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public boolean flag;
```

But my frontend dev has some issues with json for a single field,
so I am trying to keep this just as text/plain.

Some more details:

```
public Response importData(@MultipartForm MultipartBody multipartBody) {
{...]
}


public class MultipartBody {

@PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public boolean flag;

    {...]

}
```

Thanks,

Marcus